# Storyboard and custom init

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I recently tried working with the MainStoryboard.storyboard within Xcode and so far It's going pretty good and I'm wondering why I've never used it before. While playing with some code I bumped into an obstacle and I don't know how to resolve this.

When I alloc and init a new ViewController (with a custom init I declared in the ViewControllers class) I would do something like this:

```
ViewController *myViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithMyCustomData:myCustomData];
```

Then after that I could do something like:

```
[self presentViewController:myViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When I'm working with a storyboard I'm learnt that switching to a standalone ViewController requires an Identifier.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
ViewController *myViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewControllerIdentifier"];
[self presentViewController:myViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

How can I still use my custom initialization for myViewController while making use of a storyboard?

Is it ok to just do something like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
ViewController *myViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewControllerIdentifier"];
myViewController.customData = myCustomData;
[self presentViewController:myViewController animated:YES completion:nil];




//MyViewController.m
- (id) initWithMyCustomData:(NSString *) data {
if (self = [super init]) {
    iVarData = data;
}
return self;
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would just create a method which does the custom data loading.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
MyViewController *myViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewControllerIdentifier"];
[myViewController loadCustomData:myCustomData];
[self presentViewController:myViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If all your `initWithCustomData` method does is set one instance variable, you should just set it manually (no custom inits or extra methods required):

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
MyViewController *myViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewControllerIdentifier"];
myViewController.iVarData = myCustomData;
[self presentViewController:myViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems crazy that Apple don't provide a way of creating a proper custom `init` method with Storyboards.

Comment: I am not sure why one would state: "If all your initWithCustomData method does is set one instance variable, you should just set it manually (no custom inits or extra methods required)". There is no docs from Apple that state that so I would advise any reader to consider this statement a mere opinion and not a rule to follow. Plenty of initializers in iOS take even just one argument.

Comment: @zumzum Apple does use the practice of setting variables in the 'prepareForSegue: sender:' method in their example code. See the 'AddTimedReminder.m' file in the [EKReminderSuite](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/EKReminderSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015203-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) example project for an example.

Comment: @zumzum Yes this was my opinion. It seems pointless to create a method just to set one instance variable, when it could just be set directly. Obviously there are initializers that take only one argument; however, in this case where creating a custom init is a challenge, I believe this is a simpler angle of attack.

Answer (score 17):

You can instantiate viewcontroller in -init method.

```
 - (instancetype)init
 {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

   self = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];

   if(self)
   {
    //default initialization

   }
   return  self;
 }
```

and the in your custom init method

```
 - (instancetype)initWithImages:(NSArray *)images
 {
   self = [self init];

   if(self)
   {
     self.images = images;
   }

   return  self;
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is not 'feng shui' anymore, since your - (instancetype)init doesn't call superclass designated initializer.

Answer (score 3):

My version:

```
- (instancetype)initWithData (NSArray *)someData
 {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

   self = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];

   if(self)
   {
    //default initialization

   }
   return  self;
 }
```

...one initializer ;)