# UIViewController before UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I would like to have a UIViewController with a UIButton. After the user has pressed the button, the UITabBarController should appear with deferent tabs.

```
UIViewController *view1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] 
UIViewController *view2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] 
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[view1, view2];
```

How can I show a view before the UITabBarController?

Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with `UITabBarController`? You setup your app with whatever view hierarchy you need. Showing a tab controller is no different than showing any other view controller.

Comment: I agree with rmaddy, you can just modally navigate to a UITabBarController from the root Vc with that button.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this right from `appDeleguate`, you would use `setRootViewController` to set the screen to present.

**Example:**

```
ButtonViewController *btnVC = [[ButtonViewController alloc]init];
[self.window setRootViewController:btnVC];
```

**Example with NavigationController:**

```
ButtonViewController *btnVC = [[ButtonViewController alloc]init];
[self.window setRootViewController:btnVC];
UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                     initWithRootViewController:btnVC];
[self.window setRootViewController:navController];
```

Comment: It doesn't work properly because I have a UINavigationController already. Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks :)

Comment: Ok I think we are on the right track! However, when I am on the UITabBarController, a black screen with a tabBar is shown, that has no items in it. Is there a way to fix that? Thanks

Comment: @user1211109876 if you see a black screen then it must be your view not being hooked up to the controller. Read the following answers if [you are using a storyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18331941/1880431) or this answer if [you are using nibs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2225024/1880431) or you can do design through code

Answer (score 0):

Set up your tab controller as the root view controller, as usual.  Then present a modal view controller with your button.  When the button is pushed, dismiss the modal view controller.